# iPhone UItextField add image?

Tags: iphone

I like to add a picture (png) to a UITextField.
Anyone has any idea?

Thanks!

Balazs

Comment: Is there any way to make my own UI (textfiled) element, which also contains text and images?

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];

[myTextField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

myTextField.rightView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use UIImageView.

Comment: Ok!
But I like to add emoticon to the UItextfield (User Input), because I developed a client.

Thanks the answer!